# Decltype in template parameter of variable

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm working on some code with `unique_ptr`s and the like. The line is:

```
std::unique_ptr<char[], void(*)(void*)> result(..., std::free);
```

which works. I realize that the type that std::free gives is that second template parameter. I tried using:

```
std::unique_ptr<char[], decltype(std::free)> result(..., std::free);
```

which would be easier to read and less bug-prone. But I get errors related to `<memory>` and "instantiating a data member with a function type".

Would there be a way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`decltype(std::free)` yields the type of `std::free`, which is the function type `void(void*)`, not the function pointer type `void(*)(void*)`.  You need a function pointer type, which you can obtain by taking the address of `std::free`:

```
std::unique_ptr<char[], decltype(&std::free)> result(..., std::free);
                               ^
```

or by forming the function pointer type yourself:

```
std::unique_ptr<char[], decltype(std::free)*> result(..., std::free);
                                         ^
```

(I'd argue that the former is clearer.)

Comment: @user473973 You shouldn't feel stupid, given the fact that for assigning / passing function pointers you don't need the ampersand `&`, as [function names can be implicitly converted to function pointers](http://ideone.com/hqo9qB).

Comment: Hmm, that's pretty strange. Could it be because I'm using it as a template parameter?

Comment: No, it's because `decltype` determines the type of the expression where no type decay occurs. If you had done `std::decay<decltype(std::free)>::type` it would also have worked.